# Add a backend database to chrome extension

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sql-server, google-chrome-extension

I wrote a chrome extension to tooltip the mouse coordinates over the screen.
Now - I wish to write these coordinates to an SQL server.

Is there an efficient way of doing that?

Comment: Either a) enable an API in sql server on localhost and connect to it from the extension using [xhr/fetch](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr) or b) write a separate connector utility and use it via [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging).